# How to dynamically set values using builder in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-stream, builder

I have a class that processes the table results. I execute different types of queries that fetch different number of fields. I would like to design a method that takes in any result and return the corresponding output. Below is my current code -

```
TableResult result = queryJob.getQueryResults();
List<myDTO> output = new ArrayList<>();

MyDTO myDTO;

for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {
    myDTO = MyDTO.builder()
            .name((row.get(0) == null || row.get(0).getValue() == null) ? null : row.get(0).getStringValue())
            .id((row.get(1) == null || row.get(1).getValue() == null) ? null : row.get(1).getStringValue())
            .place((row.get(2) == null || row.get(2).getValue() == null) ? null : row.get(2).getStringValue())
            .message((row.get(3) == null || row.get(3).getValue() == null) ? null : row.get(3).getStringValue())
            .build();
    output.add(myDTO);
```

I don't want to hard code the index to get the value and use it in the builder. Instead I would like to iterate through the rows and assign the values in the MyDTO class. MyDTO uses builder. Is there a way to iterate through the fields and assign the values?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that *columns* in `FieldValueList row` are bound to certain indexes anyway.  The hardcoded indexes could be replaced with a loop parameter, but then a sort of `switch` statement/expression would be needed to set appropriate value in the builder:

```java
for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {
    MyDTO.Builder builder = MyDTO.builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (row.get(i) != null && row.get(i).getValue() != null) {
            String value = row.get(i).getStringValue();
            builder = switch(i) {
                case 0 -> builder.name(value);
                case 1 -> builder.id(value);
                case 2 -> builder.place(value);
                default -> builder.message(value);
            };
        }
    }
    output.add(builder.build());
}
```